# Не удается скачать исходники из удаленного репозитория Maven, но из локального все в порядке

Tags: java, maven, развертывание, amazon-s3

Есть 2 проекта java projects: `payment-common` и `payment-service`.
В `payment-common` добавлена зависимость `maven-source-plugin`:

```
<project>
    <builds>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Когда я делаю `mvn clean package`, В `target` появляется `sources.jar`, как и должно быть:

[image]

Так же тот .jar появляется в Amazon S3 после выполнения `mvn clean deploy`:

[image]

В `payment-service`есть следующая зависимость:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.***</groupId>
    <artifactId>payment-common</artifactId>
    <version>1.540.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Но когда я пытаюсь скачать sources средствами Intelij IDEA, я получаю следующую ошибку:

[image]

После чего, если сделать `mvn clean install`, Сорсы успешно скачиваются.
Что я делаю не так?

repositories в pom.xml:

```
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>cloudfront-snapshots</id>
            <name>***</name>
            <url>https://maven.***.net/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>jcenter-snapshots</id>
            <name>jcenter</name>
            <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>maven.***</id>
            <url>s3://***-maven-repo/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>maven.***</id>
            <url>s3://***-maven-repo/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>maven.***</id>
            <url>s3://***-maven-repo/</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>maven.***</id>
            <url>s3://***-maven-repo/</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
```

Comment: Без указания, т.е. свежая

Comment: это много-модульный проект?

Comment: Может с самой Idea что-то? Пробовали invalidate cache and restart? Настройки мавена какие в Idea?

Comment: @pegoopik возможно, у вас есть `.m2/settings.xml`, где вы указываете креды к амазону. а в IDEA в настройках -> maven, нужно указывать правильный путь к  m2 и settings.xml

Comment: Мне кажется, проблемма должна быть в IDEA. Подскажите, какой именно Maven Goal вызываете перед ошибкой?

Comment: Настройки антивируса/файрволла проверил?

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте настройки Maven

Always update snapshots - поставьте галочку.
Проверьте, что не нажата кнопка работы в offline режиме.
Для наглядности добавил скрин

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сложилось такое впечатление, что после выкладки в удаленный репозиторий, у вас maven не обновляет его в локальном. При install maven вроде напрямую обновляет в локальном репозитории.

Comment: Не помогло :(
Обновляет джарники, но не скачивает сорсы и доки. Мавен качает только джарники, а когда из идеи пытаюсь выкачать сорсы - падает с ошибкой. Причем из других репозиториев сорсы идея качает нормально(спринга, например сорсы качаются нормально)

Comment: добавил скрин, где подключается автоматическая загрузка